# How to have Angular2 project find javascript files in sibling directory

Tags: angular, node-modules

I have a directory with two separate folder hierarchies in it. One directory called "frontend" has a typical Angular2 project in it. A sibling of "frontend" called "common" contains plain old TypeScript business logic and Jasmine tests for that business logic. The code in the "common" folder has its own package.json and node_modules and can be built and tested independently of the Angular2 project.

However, I want the Angular project to include the "common" code in its build. It depends on the common code, but not vice-versa.

The Angular project doesn't know about the code outside its own source tree and node_modules.

Anyone know how to get the Angular project to pick up the dependencies in the "common" directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the "common" library in your `package.json` via a local path reference. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../common"
  }
}
```

Once referenced you can treat it like any other node module.

Comment: Using npm link might make more sense but this is a solid approach.